# Add React in One Minute script to Spring Boot controller

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

At [Add React to a Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) there's simple instructions to add a `React` component into a web page. This works fine run directly as a single page.

[image: react in one minute works]

However, if the same page is "hosted" in a spring boot app, with a single route per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66785716/1964277)

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
  @GetMapping("/**")
  public String react() {
      return "index.html";
  }
}
```

the text renders but not the react component.

[image: no like component]

The error in the console is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

[image: uncaught syntaxError]

If I try a direct route mapping

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String react() {
    return "index.html";
}
```

Again the react component doesn't display

[image: again no like component]

It's a `GET http://localhost:8082/like_button.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404` error

[image: 404 error]

Is the problem that to run a `react script` in `spring boot` you have to install separate React app dependencies?

/* UPDATE */

It's something to do with the `JSX` and `Babel` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70391057/1964277). If I add to the `index.html`

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"> </script>

<!-- Load our React component. -->
<script type="text/babel" src="like_button.js"></script>
```

there's no longer an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` error. The error is now:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: /http:/localhost:8082/like_button.js: Unexpected token (11:5)`

[image: unexpected token]

Comment: `http://localhost:8082/like_button.js` is this js available from that URL? Put it in the public folder of spring boot app, first it should be available at that location

Comment: can you show your like_button.js source? Looks like you're trying to use JSX (which requires further configurations)?

Comment: The like_button.js is [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gaearon/0b180827c190fe4fd98b4c7f570ea4a8/raw/b9157ce933c79a4559d2aa9ff3372668cce48de7/LikeButton.js) and then from the tutorial it adds the `const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');`
`ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);`

Comment: There is no < character in there, no JSX indeed, so why is console showing error about < character

Comment: It comes from step 3 [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute)

Comment: The `like_button.js` react component was clearly received at browser per the 200 status but produces the `<` character error in that case, but the same `like_button.js` works fine on its own (not in spring boot app)